# What are the reasons I can not ping my Cell phone/Android from my Desktop

Tags: android, web-services, ping

I have installed a simple web server on my android , The web server is running with internal IP address , I tried to ping my external cell phone IP without any result.
I tried connecting to my WiFi network and to ping with internal IP address , still no result.
Is there a blocking procedure in my carrier ?

Thanks a Lot,

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this would be for a couple of reasons. I'm not a networking whiz but the first and foremost in my mind would be some kind of firewall. From what I understand about smartphones is that you specifically have to give permission to establish a connection.
The next possible reason might be protocol. Perhaps its the carrier or the AOS method of sending packets, I'm not anywhere near 100% on this though. I could help more if my ADSL weren't down.

My suggestion is: have you tried using the phones MAC address?

Sorry for the quick n dirty response. Hope it helps some.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. How can I use the MAC address?

Comment: It will depend on which version of Android you are using. You could try ARPING the MAC address. MAC addresses are at a different level of the OSI layer (Level 2 v Level 3 for IP addresses) so you won't really be use this as a means to connect per se, but you should be able to check connectivity through it. Also if the Android is actively connected to your internal network you should be able to reach it via arp -a

Comment: Thanks on your response. Last questions. Can I reach my web server on the android via Android external IP? I can reach without any problems via my internal address of the Android. Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 3):

I think for ping call lots of techniques are applying , firstly you `establish media via sip(android sip, jsip, csipsample its your choice)` here you `get INVITE and INVITE-ACK`. And for transferring media to one to another end you use RTP (rtpsender and rtpreceiver class). After getting Acknowledgement you start rtp for send media stream.

If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: Thanks on your response. Last questions. Can I reach my web server on the android via Android external IP? I can reach without any problems via my internal address of the Android. Thanks a Lot.